# How to prove by induction that $\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

I'm about to prove that for any $a,b>0$ **and** $n\in\mathbb{N},$ the inequality: $\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}\geq\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^n$ holds.

**By induction I get**: $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\cdot\frac{a^n+b^n}{2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}+ab^n+ba^n}{2}$$ $$=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}+\frac{ab^n+ba^n}{2}\right).$$  Now I have to prove that $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}+\frac{ab^n+ba^n}{2}\right)$$ $$\leq\frac{a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}}{2}$$ $$\Leftrightarrow a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}\geq ab^n +ba^n.$$ But I don't know how to prove that one, is it possible to be proved by induction ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired inequality can be written as $0\leq (a-b)(a^n-b^n)$ this is true regardless which is bigger.

Comment: You have right, I was trying an other induction proof for that avoiding that way.

Comment: Clear and concise.  +1